# How to rearrange items in a container with drag and drop in Sencha Touch 1

Tags: sencha-touch

I need to make a list that can be rearranged using drag and drop in a Sencha Touch 1.0 app. So what I did so far is to create a panel with the items list made out of alternating draggable and droppable panels. I can drag an item to a new position and I can get figure out where I need to insert it, but the problem is I can't figure out how to actually move the item within the panel.

I tried to remove the item and insert it in the new location, but it's a bit slow and it stopped working once I changed the eventTarget on the Draggable object to point to a child of the item(the handle of the item that you have to use in order to drag it around).

```
var paragraphText = p.el.dom.outerText;
paragraphPanel.remove(paragraph, true);
paragraphPanel.insert(dropIndex, createParagraph(paragraphText));
paragraphPanel.doLayout();
```

I also tried not destroying the item and just removing it and inserting it right back in the new possition. This doesn't work at all, as in the drag is reset and nothing happens in the list, even though the code below gets executed.

```
paragraphPanel.remove(paragraph, false);
paragraphPanel.insert(dropIndex, paragraph);
paragraphPanel.doLayout();
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you resolved your problem?

Comment: For the most part. I will post an answer this weekend when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I gave up trying to use a Panel for this and I just used Ext.List instead:

```
this.paragraphList = new Ext.List({
    xtype: 'list',
    store: this.paragraphStore,
    itemTpl : '<div class="paragraph-content" >{text}</div><div class="paragraph-handle" ></div>',
    cls: 'paragraph-list',
    disableSelection: true,
    height:'100%',
    scroll: 'vertical'
});
```

This way I don't have to worry about rendering the thing, I can just update the store and the rendering will happen on it's own.Each item in the list has a Draggable but there's no Droppable objects. Instead, in the 'beforedragend' event I calculate where the item was dropped and update the store acordingly. Once you figured out the dragIndex and the dropIndex you can do something like this:

```
//if item is moving down in the list dropIndex is decremented
//because the item is first removed and then added to new position
if (dropIndex > dragIndex) {
    dropIndex--;
}

//in case the item isn't being dropped in an appropriate place
//just return and let Sencha reset the draggable object (snap back to place)
if (dropIndex == null || dropIndex == dragIndex) {
    return;
}

//this will stop the item from resetting  
//it is not in the Sencha documentation
draggable.cancelRevert = true;
this.resetAll();

var store = this.paragraphStore;
var paragraph = store.getAt(dragIndex);
store.suspendEvents(false);
store.remove(dragIndex);
store.resumeEvents();
store.insert(dropIndex, paragraph);
```

Here's a couple of extra things worth mentioning:

On the Draggable object you can use the 'eventTarget' to specify an HTML element that will initiate the drag action.  This is so you can add some graphic that acts like a handle for each element when you want to drag it.

Also you can use the 'proxy' attribute to specify the html element that is shown while dragging the item. Because the dragging actually uses css translation, it can get rather complicated if you're dragging an element of the list, while the list is scrolling for example. The proxy can be a div that is not part of the list.

For more see the Sencha documentation and have a look at their source code because there's plenty of stuff that's not documented:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Draggable

Comment: I should mention this solution still doesn't work perfectly for me. It might be because I was trying to get the items in the list to float down when you drag an item into position, so that it makes room for you to drop it in. This complicates things a lot, and it might be easier to just do some highlighting.

Also performance is a bit of a concern, especially with older hardware. If I get around to fixing these issues I'll write a blog post and update my answer.